# Conditional statements for IE

Tags: php, html, conditional-statements

I have a small problem with some conditional statements. To simplify the problem I have shown a small example below. I have a feeling I may be approaching this in the wrong way, anyone shed any light on them for me?

Basically I want to show an iframed video on IE7 and lower and an object video on > IE7

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
     <iframe></iframe>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if (gt IE 7)|!(IE)]><!-->
    <object></object>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

However, IE6 outputs both and i'm concerned other browsers may output none. Thoughts?

Comment: Not really an answer but are you really going to support browsers older than 6 years? I doubt that anybody using IE <= 7 is likely to have a decent browsing experience.

Comment: Unfortunately just something we have to do due to large numbers of visitors from overseas countries still very actively using older IE browsers.

Comment: And by handling them with specific (and incorrect / not standard) code you are not helping them quit! (ie upgrade)

Comment: Please only answer my question if you have the answer. I have a task, I want to know how to achieve it. I care not for personal opinions of IE6 or IE7 haters. I'm not paid for that. However strongly I may agree with you.

Comment: @David educating clients, users and misinformed developers is also a task for most of us. If you do not like the comments I am sorry but for a reason this is a part to post comments, not answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as you've already catered for <=IE7, you only need to do other stuff for >=IE8, so this will work:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
  <iframe></iframe>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 8]>
  <object></object>
<![endif]-->
```

And the syntax is a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

IE6 is not supported by most major websites around the world, so it's definately not something you need to worry yourself with.

[Here](http://www.ie6countdown.com/) are some nice stats about IE6 usage around the world. It basically means that if your website isn't made specifically for Chinese, you shouldn't bother - AND ( as @Alec stated in a comment) - it is important for your clients to be informed as well, because it can save time for both you and the client (and smart clients appreciate tips from well informed developers).

Just as a sidenote, Google dropped support for IE 8 ( !!! ) a few months ago. Read more [here](http://www.webmonkey.com/2012/09/google-drops-support-for-ie-8-windows-xp/).

Answer (score 0):

In the end I fixed my own problem with the following code.

```
<!--[if IE 7]>

<![endif]-->

<!--[if (lt IE 7)|!(IE)]><!-->

<!--<![endif]-->
```